# Duda sobre Herencias en Python

Tags: python, class, herencia

Tengo una duda respecto a las herencias em Python, este es mi código de ejemplo:

```
class Clase1:
    def metodo1(self):
        print("Hola soy el método 1 de la clase 1")

class Clase2:
    def metodo2(self):
        print("Hola soy el método 2 de la clase 2")

class Clase3(Clase1,Clase2):
    def metodo3(self):
        print("Hola soy el método 3 de la clase 3")


c= Clase3()

c.metodo1()

c.metodo2()

c.metodo3()
```

Asi como esta el codigo, si a la Clase2 le digo que herede las caractericas de la Clase1 de la siguiente forma **Clase2(Clase1)**, ¿por que hacer esto me genera un error?

Comment: ¿qué dice el error? edita la pregunta para añadirlo

Answer (score 1):

Esto ocurre por que se genera un error interno al momento de elegir que método usar, ya que si clase 2 hereda de clase 1, cuando clase 3 herede de clase dos ya estará heredando a su vez de clase 1, por lo que no es necesario que herede de clase 1.
Actualmente el diagrama de tu clase es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual tiene sentido, sin embargo el otro caso que planteas quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se ve el problema, imagina que quieres ejecutar el método 1, ¿De donde lo obtendrías? directamente de la clase 1 o a través de la clase 2, aquí es donde ocurre el error, ya que python no sabe cual elegir, por lo que si clase 2 hereda de clase 1, la clase 3 ya no va a heredar directamente de esta quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado de manera clara.